# Set the default value in select list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select

If I have only one option in my dropdownlist, I need to select this option as default. How can I do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are new to SO, the usual procedure here is to provide some code of your own efforts on the matter before posting. That said, this is simple JQuery:

Edit to fit new specifications:

```
if($("#select_id option").length == 2){ //if there are exactly 2 options in the select element
    $("#select_id option:nth(1)").attr("selected",true); //take the second option (element 0) inside the element with id "select_id" and set the selected attribute.
} //I think we do not need an else if any other thing will select the first option by default
```

Anyway, first option should be selected by default.

```
<select id="select_id">
    <option value=1>First option is selected by default</option>
</select>
<!--adding proof that it is selected-->
<script>
    $(function(){
         alert($("#select_id").val()); //this will alert 1, since is the value of my first option
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The amount of options on my drop-down list is variable and dynamic. The first option is automatically selected but is empty by default. I should count the options and if there are 2 autoselect the second ...

Comment: to be clear, if there are 3 you should autoselect the thirs, 4->fourth and so on?

Comment: if there are 3 you should autoselect the first "empty field".

Comment: so, only if there are 2, we should autoselect second option?

Comment: I think I understand, now I modified code to select the second option only if there are 2 options (anything else, do nothing, so autoselect first one)